# Error after setting up site localy

Tags: files

I have set up a site locally .I took db using from live site "Backup and Migrate data".I done all editing in `settings.php` file for pointing to local db.

It works fine except two errors:

1. The specified file temporary://fileZGB3Go could not be copied, because the destination directory is not properly configured. This may be caused by a problem with file or directory permissions.
2. The specified file temporary://filelXQxcP could not be copied, because the destination directory is not properly configured. This may be caused by a problem with file or directory permissions.

Is it db error that these files are imported or something else ?

Comment: Please check below thread on drupal.org which might help you.
https://www.drupal.org/node/2359481

Comment: its not enough .I did all that explained there but it does't work out.

Comment: Check the Temporary files location in filesystem settings. Drupal can't make temp dir on your local maschine.

Comment: where to check ?? which folder ??

Comment: log in as admin and then admin/config/media/file-system

Comment: so what up next ????

Comment: try to delete temp dir manually from fiilesystem. drupal should be able to make that dir on his own with default .htaccess file inside. if not, you have wrong permission in your local webserver

Comment: can't able to delete ...how to change permissions of local webserver

Comment: point the temporary dir from admin/config/media/file-system to another non existend dir. like if you have tmp right now, to temp. drupal will then create that dir. webserver question depends on your webserver like apache or nginx and is another topic.

Comment: tmp could not be change to temp ...

Comment: it is not a drupal problem, but webserver. writepermissions are false. You could check on your filesystem if those dirs have read only permissions first and try to adjust accordingly.

Comment: i have created another directory "tmp01" in sites/default/files/ and set its permissions t0 777 and then change path at admin/configration/media/filesystem also but error still remains ...Can't understand what kind of permission it is asking for..

Comment: have you considered to install drupal from scratch and then copying modules, themes and import db to the new installation?

Comment: sites/default/files/tmp ,i could not able change permission of "tmp" directory. It displays error "Operation could not permitted" .Moreover when i right clicked on directory and go through the Permission tab it displays that "You are not owner of this directory"

Comment: no i just clone it from git and i get db from live site by "Backup and Migrate"....